# CSS is not rendered for a second after loading a webpage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js, styled-components

CSS is not rendered for a second when i load a webpage which is created with React, Next.js, Material UI, and Styled-component. My website is not SSR, but this issue is similar https://github.com/ks-rogers/react-date-picks/issues/7

This is the website which has the issue
https://swipe-cards.herokuapp.com/

In local environment, it doesnt happen.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe it is trying to load the consent of those girls to appear in a public page, and it fails.

Comment: this happened with other websites which dont have pictures. @NicolasHevia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you use the appjs as in the official example
   https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_app.js
2. Make sure you use document js like in example:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js

In addition, use a material ui loader in your appjs to show loading progress.

```
    import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';
    .....
    const [isLoading, setLoadingState] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {

        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
          setLoadingState(true);
        });
    
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
          setLoadingState(false);
        });
    
        router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => {
          setLoadingState(false);
        });

....
...
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
      ........
      {isLoading? (  
        <>
          <div className="pageLoader">
            <LinearProgress />
          </div>
```